# How can i consider future web browser releases when developing asp.net mvc web application using Jquery

Tags: jquery, browser

I am developing an asp.net mvc 3 web application where i am using Jquery on almost every view. And i am testing my application on three different browsers (IE 9, firefox 12, chrome) to make sure that my application works well on these browsers.

But my question is; **if my application is currently working well on these three browsers, then can i guarantee that they will still work well on any future releases of these web browsers without the need to do any modification to my application code.**

**If the answer is NO (i cannot guarantee ),** then what is the best way to minimize the risk and effort of any future work that might be needed. 
BR

Answer (score 0):

A) You may want to create unit tests using something like Jasmine. You may then want to run cron jobs to run your jasmine tests and then report back if something breaks. This is especially useful if your code base is constantly changing.

B) If you use a single version of jQuery and never upgrade you the run the risk of browser changes not being captured in jQuery. That being said if use a cdn version of the latest release you run the risk of deprecation warnings or errors.

C) If you use jQuery (or some other framework) it should minimize the need to manage these browser changes that may occur, and while this may not be perfect you will be close to almost never making modifications to your code. Nothing is perfect though and you also find that with more users things break that you didn't expect them to, and in very odd ways at that.

Finally, by using libraries that are managed by other people you essentially gain whole teams of people working on your project. The more you can utilize from some third party library the less code you need to maintain. This holds true only when the projects are well managed of course!